# Why do some USB extension cables have an extended shroud at the female end?

Tags: usb, cable

Some of the USB 2 extension cables in my collection have an extra sheath or shroud at the female end, with the type-A socket recessed inside by a few millimeters.

Is there a reason for this? Is it standardized or documented anywhere?

In the attached photo, from left to right, the type-A socket is,

- Flush with the sheath, works with all plugs and devices.
- Recessed about 3mm, works with most plugs and devices.
- Recessed about 5mm, works with very few plugs and devices.

The cable lengths are approximately 32in, 16in, and 20in, respectively. They are passive extension cables.

[image: USB Cable comparison]

Comment: Note, I googled various permutations of "usb extension" with "sheath", "shroud", and "recessed", but I could not find an answer.

Comment: One of those look like an active cable.  What are the lengths of these cables?  USB 2 or USB 3?

Comment: From left to right. 32in, 16in, 20in. USB 2. They aren't active, as far as I can tell. No enumeration when I plug any of them in.

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact these are extension usb cables, which I have only ever seen being active, as for the differences I suspect that’s linked to their length.

Comment: The white cable seems to be a special case.  Beside  the recessed connector, it also has a ferrite choke on it.  I have a dozen (passive) USB extension cables of various lengths (6" to 10'), and all have a minimal recess or shroud, and no ferrite donuts.

Comment: USB2 extension cables are illegal from USB specification standpoint. So no test procedures nor acceptance criteria are there, and anyone can craft whatever they feel. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Despite the USB specification, variations of USB extension cables are in widespread use, e.g. the connections between a motherboard and the front-panel ports of a desktop case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB 2.0 extension cables are illegal from USB specification standpoint. This is because the extra imperfection along USB 2.0 transmission line causes massive degradation of signal integrity.

So no test procedures nor acceptance criteria are there, and anyone can craft whatever they feel. There are more variants of overmolds, like this one below. Use at your own risk. Works fine for me though.

[image: An example of a USB cable without a protective sheath around the connector.]

Comment: http://sdphca.ucsd.edu/lab_equip_manuals/usb_20.pdf - page 120 of the pdf (labelled page 92) under "6.4.4 Prohibited Cable Assemblies" - Ali's right here.

Comment: Accepted this as it does answer "Is it standardized or documented anywhere?". Thanks @JourneymanGeek for the specific techinical reference.